# Access to XMLHttpRequest at "http://...." origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am trying to call an api where i got stuck with the CORS error.

when i tried with "https://...." , i hit the following error with service being failed.

status Code: 422.

OPTIONS https://xyz/login?username=xxx&password=xxx 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xyz/login?username=xxx&password=xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

when i tried with  "http://...." i get the following error.

status Code: 307 Temporary Redirect

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xyz/login?username=xxx&password=xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I tried adding headers but the added headers won't show on the browser.

Request headers look like below:

Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36

Please help me resolve the issue,

my component.ts looks like this

````
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../services';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
  loginForm: FormGroup;
   returnUrl: string;
   error = '';

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           username: ['', [Validators.required , Validators.email]],
           password: ['', [Validators.required]]
       });

       // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
       this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
   }

   get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, 
            this.f.password.value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.error = error;
                });
    }

}```

and my authentication.service.ts looks like this 

``import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
      const httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
       })
     };
        return this.http.post(`https://xyz/login 
                         username=xxx&password=xxx, httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(user => {
                if (user) {
                    // some logic
                }
                return user;
            }));
    }
}```

i want to resolve the CORS issue and make successful api call either from client side or from server side. Being fairly new to angular, any details/step by step instructions are appreciated.

Also , i would want to know why added headers wont show on browser. Am i missing anything
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4.3 HttpClient doesn't send Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901160/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-authorization-header)

Comment: This issue is because of backend CORS configuration, add CORS allow '*' in backend code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've used fetch api with cors-anywhere proxy to resolve the issue.

```
onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: IUserLogin, valid: boolean }) {
  let result;
  const params = {
    "username": value.username,
    "password": value.password
  }

  let url = `https://company.com/login?username=${params.username}&password=${params.password}`;
  const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  let req = new Request(proxyurl + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {

      'Authentication': `Basic ${value.username}:${value.password}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'mode': 'no-cors'

    }
  });

  fetch(req)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((contents) => {
      result = JSON.parse(contents);
      console.log(JSON.parse(contents).data)
      if (result.data) {
       // do something
      } else {
       // do something
      }
    })
    .catch(() => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?"))


}
```

Comment: Later after a while , herokuapp use to block our domain for a few mins (when they had to refresh the limit count)as they have limited number of hits . Resolved this issue by hosting my own proxy.

Comment: Saved my hours, Thanks mate, I'll use my own proxy. This worked

Answer (score 7):

CORS issues are common when developing from localhost. You have some options to fix this:

1) If you have control of your server, add this header to the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

2) If you do not own the server with the endpoint, install [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en). This will add the header and allow localhost requests.

3) If you dont use chrome or if you want to use a proxy in your code, use [this proxy](https://corsproxy.github.io/). Your urls will end up something like this:

```
https://crossorigin.me/http://xyz/login?username=xxx&password=xxx
```

Comment: Using this extension will you have issues when deploying the app?

Comment: @Rodrigo You should not use option 3 in production. Option 2 is just a chrome extension so nothing will be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little bit too late with this answer, but..
1st issue:
If back-end app doesn't return Access-Control-Allow-Origin then you can add it to security configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.headers()
            .addHeaderWriter(
                    new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "address for your front-end here")
            );
}
```